# Descargar un archivo de una carpeta de un servidor por medio de php

Tags: php

Tengo esta tabla en php y quiero que al presionar el Num de Folio me descargue el archivo ".xls" del servidor con el nombre según su Folio por ejemplo, "Si presiono el folio 130, me tiene que descargar el archivo 130.xls"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código:

```
foreach ($query as $valor) { 
    echo '<tr> <td nowrap style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_self" href="javascript:SelCalen(\''. $valor[0] .'\',\''. $valor[2] .'\',\''. $v01 .'\');" >' . $valor[0] . '</a></td> <td style="width: 100px;" nowrap class="center">' . $valor[1] . '</td> <td nowrap style="width: 200px; text-align:left;">' . $valor[2] . '</td> <td nowrap class="center"> ' .$valor[3] . '</td> <td nowrap class="center">' . $valor[4] . '</td> </tr>'; 
} 

echo '</tbody>';
```

Y esto lo tengo para descargar el .xls

```
// Definimos el nombre de archivo a descargar. 
$filename = "100.xls"; 

// Ahora guardamos otra variable con la ruta del archivo 
$file = "functions/".$filename; 

// Aquí, establecemos la cabecera del documento 
header("Content-Description: Descargar imagen"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file)); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 

readfile($file);
```

Comment: Incluye el código que tienes hasta ahora para generar la tabla

Comment: foreach ($query as $valor) {
          echo  '<tr>
    <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_self" href="javascript:SelCalen(\''. $valor[0] .'\',\''. $valor[2] .'\',\''. $v01 .'\');" >' . $valor[0] . '</a></td>
                    <td style="width: 100px;" nowrap class="center">'  . $valor[1] . '</td>
             
       <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:left;">'  . $valor[2] . '</td>
   <td nowrap class="center"> '  .$valor[3] . '</td> <td nowrap class="center">'  . $valor[4] . '</td> </tr>';
          }
          echo '</tbody>';

Comment: Este lo tengo para descargar ell .xls
// Definimos el nombre de archivo a descargar.
 $filename = "100.xls";
 // Ahora guardamos otra variable con la ruta del archivo
 $file = "functions/".$filename;
 // Aquí, establecemos la cabecera del documento
 header("Content-Description: Descargar imagen");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
 header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
 header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 readfile($file);

Comment: @ArurodeGyy Y cuál es el problema o la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que sería mas sencillo darle a tu `a` el comportamiento por defecto, dejando que su `href` tenga la URL del fichero a descargar.

Sólo te quedaría pasar la función Javascript que usas en el `a` a su contenedor; todo quedaría mas o menos como (sin probar):

```
foreach($query as $valor){
    $sFila = <<<FILA
    <tr>
        <td nowrap style="width: 200px; text-align:center;" onclick="SelCalen('{$valor[0]}','{$valor[2]}','{$v01}');">
            <a target="_self" href="http://tudominio.tld/ruta_del_fichero/{$valor[0]}.xls" >{$valor[0]}</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px;" nowrap class="center">{$valor[1]}</td>
        <td nowrap style="width: 200px; text-align:left;">{$valor[2]}</td>
        <td nowrap class="center"> {$valor[3]}</td>
        <td nowrap class="center">{$valor[4]}</td>
    </tr>
FILA;
    echo $sFila;
}
```

Lo he cambiado a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para mejorar la lectura, pero debería funcionar igual tal como lo pusiste tú.

Una última cosa: tienes al final de la llamada `SelCalen` una variable `$v01` que no sé si es externa al bucle o una confusión.

Yo lo haría de forma no obstrusiva, pero ese es otro asunto ;)

Answer (score 0):

yo creo que deberias poner la ruta de los archivos en bd y después solo seleccionarlos desde el download php y listo así los descargas y lo único que recuperas es el id de la tabla